# Is the password of postgresql installed with docker automatically changed?

Tags: postgresql, docker, passwords

I created the postgresql docker with the command below

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

But after some time, the following error occurs

```
[575] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
[575] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

Run the command below and it will work again

```
docker exec postgres su - postgres -c "psql -U postgres -d postgres -c \"alter user postgres with password '1234';\""
```

Can you tell me why this is happening?